Solution to two-variable linear recurrence with alternating rules for even and odd terms
I’m working with the following recurrence for integers $i \ge 0$, $j \ge 1$. Here $r > 0$ is some fixed integer. The terms $a_{i, j}$ satisfy the boundary conditions $a_{0, 1} = r, a_{1, 1} = 2r, a_{2, 1}  = r$, and $a_{i, j} = 0$ for $i > 2j$. When $i = 2k$, $a_{i, j} = a_{i, j - 1} + a_{i-1, j - 1} + a_{i - 2, j - 1}$. When $i = 2k + 1$, $a_{i, j} = a_{i, j - 1} + 2a_{i-1, j - 1} + a_{i - 2, j - 1}$. I’ve tried a few things but don’t know how to find a closed-form solution (it feels like one should exist, given the similarity to the recurrence for binomial coefficients). I would greatly appreciate help in finding a solution or general techniques for this type of recurrence.
EDIT: I realized a generating function approach works. I will write out all the details when I have time.

A general technique for any kind of linear recurrence is to find the generating function. Extracting coefficients is another beast though…
